# Background of URI and filepath in Android

Tags: android, file

My app needs to read an image file and store the location in a settings database.

I found how to grab an image using the ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent that opens the media selector. It returns a Uri that looks like `content://media/external/images/media/78`

I understand this allows saving every kind of data source, not only files. I still have two questions about that.

How is this resolved to an actual file in a folder? Is a database maintained that builds a relation between the number and the very different filename?

If the app wants a local file as a background file for this scenario, should I save this Uri in the preferences or better the real filepath?

Comment: see `ContentResolver`  / `ContentProvider` class documentation, and yes, always use `Uri`,  not any "real path" which in most cases you cannot get from `Uri`

Comment: I found different examples how to use it, though there often are comments saying this won't work under some circumstances or API levels. But I am also curious how this works, a number is thrown in and this number points to the correct file.

Comment: ok see the answer below by NehaK - never use it - there is no any universal `getFilePathFromURI` method - if you want to use it you will have problems sooner or later

Comment: I am already using it in my project.. and I did't see any issue till now...

Comment: If you dont want to use that that's fine.. but dont decrease my reputation by giving negative points....

Comment: @NehaK your method is basically **wrong** - more [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) - and if you dont believe it see how many versions of `getRealFilePathFromURI` method is on stackoverflow - all of them are wrong

Comment: Basically..... I provided a solution that someone needed... I am not super expert to tell which is wrong or right... For me the method worked for me is right...

Comment: Holy sh.. your link also explains that this Uri is not valid for long. Such a pain... so every app that wants to choose and persist a background image does such effort? Or would I better load the image chosen by Uri and save it to a dedicated place on my own?

Comment: See your linked site: **How Long Can I Use the Uri? Not long** it's only valid for the process but not after that. I need to grab a file and have to link to it for months, until the user choses something new or it can't be found any more.

Comment: i never saw content providers that change their `Uri`s by theirs own - i cannot imagine that once obtained they would point to completely different content

Comment: Well this page says this... I have no proof if this is true or not. Where can I find how this works? Where is the matching between this number and the file? Especially for my app, what about loading the image once it's coming with it's Uri and save the image to a dedicated place? That would avoid any trouble with Uri and filepaths.

Comment: it says "not long" in the terms of permissions not the content, for example [contact provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider) uses `Uri`s everywhere and i cannot imagine that the uri pointing a your ago to "john smith" now points to "jane williams" - otherwise it would be a useless concept

Comment: `"Where can I find how this works? Where is the matching between this number and the file?"` - for `content://media` see  http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/packages/providers/MediaProvider/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java